# Dart: QuerySnapshot clear all documents don't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with the following code snippet that i don't understand:

```
QuerySnapshot _assignments;
print('Length before clear: ${_assignments.documents.length}');
_assignments.documents.clear();
print('Length after clear: ${_assignments.documents.length}');
```

I have a QuerySnapshot and i will clear all documents from the QuerySnapshot, but when i clear the QuerySnapshot nothing happens. The length from the QuerySnapshot is the same as before. Can anyone please help me and explain this? And how can i clear/delete a QuerySnapshot (length = 0)?

Comment: add your full code

Answer (score 0):

```
_assignments.documents.delete();
```

You can try this

Comment: I have no function delete() for _assignments.documents